# IP Address Direct Assignment

Tags: ip

What does it mean when a "whois" report says that an IP Address is owned by CloudFlare and the "net type" is "direct assignment"?   example follows:

```
NetRange: 104.16.0.0 - 104.31.255.255
CIDR: 104.16.0.0/12
NetName: CLOUDFLARENET
NetHandle: NET-104-16-0-0-1
Parent: NET104 (NET-104-0-0-0-0)
NetType: Direct Assignment
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

To quote [Introduction to ARIN's Database](https://www.arin.net/resources/guide/account/database/):

> **Direct Assignment** : IP address space assigned directly from ARIN to an organization for its own exclusive use.

So this IP space cannot be used to do sub allocations to downstream customers, that's what **Direct Allocation** is for.

Comment: I believe the address 104.16.0.195 was used by Cobb County, GA last year, but it is held by CloudFlare now, and doesn't show up in https://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host=104.16.0.195&t=1 .   Do you know how I can verify that it was (or wasn't) used by Cobb County last year?

Comment: I really have no idea. ARIN has a historical whois service that may be of help: https://www.arin.net/reference/research/whowas/